# (Pxl5) Audio via JBL speaker becomes fractured after some minutes

Tags: bluetooth, audio, google-pixel, bluetooth-audio

The following is a consistent problem (reproduces always):

1. Connecting phone to speaker and turning music on
2. Music is played, un-fractured.
3. Within 30 minutes (maybe less), music becomes very fractured: most of the time you can't hear anything, once every few seconds, about one second bit of the music is played.
4. When awakening the phone (clicking any button), the music immediately returns for another fracture, then problem continues.

Models:

- Phone: Pixel 5, Android v. 12
- Speaker: JBL GO 2

Troubleshoot:

- Tried with another JBL GO 2 - problem persists.
- When using Jabra bluetooth earphones - problem does **not** persist.
- Didn't check for other speakers or bluetooth audio equipment.
- Didn't check for music players other than Spotify.

Comment: I love JBL speakers, but I have similar issues connecting to them with Bluetooth.  I thus have to wonder if their tech has trouble with Bluetooth connections.  Seems unlikely, but the symptoms exhibited are repeatable.